# Zoom the graphs in Jupyter

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to view in the graph in zoomed version in python. I tried the following commands but it did not work. Could anyone please help?

```py
import mpld3
mpld3.enable_notebook()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it did not work"? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 4):

If you are working in Jupyter Notebook, you can just use the magic command `%matplotlib notebook`. This enables all the plots to be viewed in the interactive mode, where you can zoom, which is what I assume you want to do.

However, sometimes it doesn't work when you have used `%matplotlib inline` before. In this case, just restart the kernel and rerun the notebook.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on that?